# Как создать передвигающуюся стрелку в меню?

Tags: css3, html5, css

Помогите создать такое же меню: http://promsite.info/faq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вот это поможет: [меню для сайта с помощью jQuery](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=29&id=535). И вот точно такое же меню: [Меню в стиле лава-лампы на CSS3](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=2&id=1411).

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - это использовать 
[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
При том вам нужно разобраться с тем, что такое `position:absolute` и получение координат элемента меню через `jquery` (или любым другим способом).

Answer (score 2):

В примере хрень :)

Лучше, если бы стрелочка имела положение курсора.

1. Стрелочке задаём position: absolute, чтоб потом не мучиться с цифрами.
2. При передвижении курсора задавать left (анимацией) равный позиции курсора (заранее обрабатываем, чтоб сумма позиции курсора и ширины стрелки была меньше или равна длины всего меню и больше или равна отступу от меню слева).

[Получение позиции курсора](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-tip-how-to-get-mouse-cursor.html)